# MacBook Pro External DVI Monitor Full Resolution not available

Tags: mac, display, resolution, macbook, dvi

I have a new macBook Pro 13" and a 30" apple monitor.  I am connecting this monitor via a DVI, and am unable to retrieve a list of all the supported resolutions for the 30" monitor.  The Mac book only allows be the same resolution range as its built in screen.  How can I change the resolution on the Mac Book to increase the resolution on the 30" external monitor.

Thanks,

Comment: I presume that this was downvoted because whoever did it is, like me, envious beyond reason.  But seriously, have you asked Apple for some help.

Comment: IF i recall i dont think you an use a res beyond the max for the laptop if your are using the other display in tandem (ie. dual displays). In order to use the full res i think you have to use it as the only display. And if its like the old PowerBooks then youll have to have a mouse and keyboard attached and the lid closed.

Comment: Above comment is incorrect.  I had this problem with a 30inch monitor I tried, though I can use 24inch monitors at much higher resolution than the laptop itself (with both external and built-in displays working).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried going to System Preferences -> Display? When you have the 30" display plugged in, there should be an Arrangement tab, where you can uncheck the  *Mirror Displays* setting. This should give you access to the resolutions of the 30" display.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the Mini DisplayPort to DVI or the Mini DisplayPort to Dual Link DVI port? The standard DVI adapter won't be able to run the full resolution of a 30" monitor, and you'll require the more expensive [Mini Display Port to Dual Link DVI](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB571Z/A) adapter to use the full 2560x1600 resolution.

Comment: I suspect that this is the answer that Mr. Sammur is looking for.

Comment: Chealion, thanks so much! I'm so frustrated that I didn't realize this when trying to buy a 30-inch monitor today at B&H.  I finally gave up, thinking my laptop just couldn't drive that resolution.  I guess I'll go back tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same cable & monitor and the same problem. Solved by using a stock HDMI to Mini DisplayPort cable. My colleague notes that some pre 2012 MacBooks are picky about the quality of the HDMI cables, but my 2012 15" Retina MBP worked fine with the cheaper cable.